# MySQL or PHP: Find optimum combination of rows based on score

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with the following columns

```
Flavour1| Flavour2      | Score
-------------------------------------
Vanilla | Strawberry    | 7
Choc    | Toffee        | 8
Vanilla | Choc          | 6
Toffee  | Vanilla       | 7
```

Etc.

I want to be able to select N rows from the table which, in combination, have the highest total score, but are subject to restrictions on the number of times each flavour can feature.

For example, I may want to choose the 5 best flavour combinations (rows) with no single flavour appearing more than 3 times (count of Flavour1+Flavour2 < 3)

I'm struggling to get my head around how to do it due to the fact the db has to compare all combinations to get the score, whilst keeping count of the number of times a flavour has featured.

Any help much appreciated!!

EDIT - if there's an algorithmic way to do this in PHP that would also be acceptable.

Comment: Well this is obviously wrong. Toffee|Vanilla should have the highest score! :-) Anyway, consider providing a more properly representative data set (ideally as a set of DDLs and/or sqlfiddle) together with the corresponding result set.

Comment: Is the order of flavors important? I mean if you have Toffee|Vanilla|7 does it also mean that Vanilla|Toffee|7?

Comment: The order isn't important but all the possible combinations will be present as rows in the table with a score which might change in future.

Answer (score 0):

As specified, there is no "efficient" way to do this in SQL.  You can do this by generating all combinations and then applying the rules you want in a `where` clause.  Let me also assume that you have an `id` on each column, uniquely identifying a pair.

In your case, because you allow duplicates, I would add a count to each combination and use that for the combination:

```
create view v_withcounts as
    select t.*, 1 as cnt
    from table t
    union all
    select t.*, 2 as cnt
    from table t
    union all
    select t.*, 3 as cnt
    from table t;
```

Then for the query:

```
select v1.id, coalesce(v1.cnt),
       v2.id, coalesce(v2.cnt),
       v3.id, coalesce(v3.cnt),
       v4.id, coalesce(v4.cnt),
       v5.id, coalesce(v5.cnt)
from v_withcounts v1 left join
     v_withcounts v2
     on v2.id not in (v1.id) left join
     v_withcounts v3
     on v3.id not in (v1.id, v2.id) left join
     v_withcounts v4
     on v4.id not in (v1.id, v2.id, v3.id) left join
     v_withcounts v2
     on v5.id not in (v1.id, v2.id, v3.id, v4.id)
where (coalesce(v1.cnt, 0) + coalesce(v2.cnt, 0) + coalesce(v3.cnt, 0) +
       coalesce(v4.cnt, 0) + coalesce(v5.ccnt, 0)
      ) = 5
```

Algorithmically, there are probably more efficient ways to solve this problem.  I suspect that a greedy algorithm would be much faster and would generate your desired result.

Comment: Thank you - I can see how this would work but it times out on my MySQL server, so I'm assuming I should do it in PHP algorithmically. Any thoughts?

Comment: @user1491032 . . . First, try this on a small subset of data and see if the logic does work.  You will have a similar problem in php, because you will have to create a 5-way cartesian product to solve the problem as you have described it.